# Wcf data service - 401 error

Tags: jquery, wcf, authentication, http-status-code-401

Im building a public web site where you need to be logged in and i have been using asmx-services up to now. Now i want to try Wcf data service instead and query the service via jQuery.

It all works fine on localhost but once i publish my web site i get this error:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I have mapped my database using Entity Data Model and then i created a wcf data service which is connected to my Data Model like this:

```
public class MyService : DataService<MyEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {

        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;

        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

    }
}
```

where MyEntities is specified when mapping my Entity Data Model to my database.

As i wrote, it all works fine on localhost, i can query my service like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/OData/MyService.svc/Groups",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
//some logic
}});
```

but when i use the published version I get the 401-error. (i get the same error when writing the query directly in the browser)

I'm really green using Wcf-services so i really need help to make this work, i have tried to Google but with no luck. Do i need to do any configuration in my service or in web.config or in the IIS?

Im using IIS 7.0 and asp.net 4.0

Comment: *Now i want to try Wcf data service instead using OData* : ahem.... WCF Data Services is Microsoft's concrete **implementation** of OData......

Comment: I see, as i said, i am very green in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 401 is a HTTP error - Access denied.

This is coming from IIS before it reaches your server side c# code.

How to fix it depends on what your authentication is. But the basic idea is that the request must contain enough authentication information for the request to be accepted by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, the specified user did not have read permissions on the disk. Sometimes it can seem hard but be so simple.

Case closed.